# FCM is not delivering push to client using HTTP v1

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-fcm

Does anyone facing issue with fcm to delivery push notification with HTTP v1?

I've an scenario in which I'm having strange issue. When I'm running an debug build or release build in my mobile, I'm able to receive push notification in device with high priority but when I'm sending push notification to those users who have downloaded same build from play store, they're not receiving push notification on device side.
While I'm not getting any error response from fcm service https://fcm.googleapis.com/.../projects/messages:send when sending push notification to client who have downloaded from play store. While using same API, it's delivering push to client's device who've installed direct .apk file.

Can anyone have an idea or might have faced similar issue in past?